# Microsoft Outlook versus iCal versus Google Calendar

Tags: macos, google-calendar, ms-office

The corporate calendar and email server is Exchange. My personal calendar is in google.

Currently, I use iCal to allow me to see both calendars at the same time.

This is not perfect, however, insofar as iCal doesn't support all of Exchange's calendar protocol. When people propose new times for meetings, for example, unpleasant things happen.

So, I wonder if there's some way to get Outlook 2011 to cooperate with Google calendar, with or without help from iCal, so that I could use Outlook to manipulate the work calendar and still see my Google calendar as I go.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From http://www.google.com/support/forum/p/Calendar/thread?tid=044fe4493f88eba1&hl=en&start=80

peertimo
Level 1
1/4/11

"One confirmed hint: Spanning Sync works. First you have to set up Apple iCal with the same Exchange as Outlook. Then Spanning Sync can sync one way from that "shared"/same calendar and Google Calendar. Once it is there, you can sync it back down to your iPhone and iPad as a regular Google Exchange sync."

Comment: Great workaround! I've been wanting to use Google a bit at work. Seems like a very reasonable solution given the alternative.